# API call from React App doesn't work on mobile

Tags: reactjs, api

I have a React project online (https://versifiction.github.io/api-ratp/horaires) which makes an API call to get the schedules of the public transports in Paris,

It works on desktop but when I try to do the API call on mobile, it doesn't work
I don't understand why, can somebody help me ?

**If you want to do a test, here what you can enter in the select and the inputs :**

**- first select, choose "Metros",**

**- first input, type "6"**

**- second input, type "Nation"**

**You can also use the datalist by clicking on the little arrow in the inputs after chosen a transport with the select**

Thanks !

Comment: The link you've provided doesn't work. Did you try to check if it works on different desktop browsers ? Also did you try to resize the desktop browser to the size of a mobile to see if the API call works then ?

Comment: the link works for me, the following link doesnt work too ?https://versifiction.github.io/api-ratp/, and it works even if i resize to an iphone8 resolution on desktop, but not on mobile

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the fetching itself and not the mobile/ desktop view. I tried to open the link you've provided and i get these errors. It's probably working on your desktop because the information might be cached.

[image: Error messages i get in console]

As you can see the main error is T[4] is undefined. Try changing your desktop browser and clearing the cache of the browser you use at the moment if it still works.

Comment: ok thank you man, but that's crazy because it works on desktop and not on mobile... i still didn't find where the issue is (if you have some time here is the react component of this : https://github.com/Versifiction/api-ratp/blob/master/src/Components/Molecules/HorairesContent/index.js)